# Check Internet connection availability

Tags: vba, excel

Using the following code, with the help of [this post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/check-internet-availability-using-vba/627e3bc4-2168-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5), I'm checking if the user has a working Internet connection:

```
Private Declare Function InternetGetConnectedState _
   Lib "wininet.dll" (ByRef dwflags As Long, _
   ByVal dwReserved As Long) As Long
Private Const INTERNET_CONNECTION_MODEM As Long = &H1
Private Const INTERNET_CONNECTION_LAN As Long = &H2
Private Const INTERNET_CONNECTION_PROXY As Long = &H4
Private Const INTERNET_CONNECTION_OFFLINE As Long = &H20
Function IsInternetConnected() As Boolean
    Dim L As Long
    Dim R As Long
    R = InternetGetConnectedState(L, 0&)
    If R = 0 Then
        IsInternetConnected = False
    Else
        If R <= 4 Then
            IsInternetConnected = True
        Else
            IsInternetConnected = False
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

This is returning the following error, which seems to be related with 64-bit systems:

[image]

How can I adapt this code to both 32-64 systems in a reliable way?

Perhaps checking the user system and the response from google.com?

Comment: you need to use precompilers like #if vba7.... google precompilers declaring ptrsafe or something, not in excel at minute and cant remember fully :)

Comment: @user5414798 ok, thanks anyway, I'll have a look at what precompilers are!

Comment: Have a read of this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691831(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `PtrSafe` to the declaration for Win 64 bits:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function InternetGetConnectedState _
   Lib "wininet.dll" (ByRef dwflags As Long, _
   ByVal dwReserved As Long) As Long
```